# react native spinner dropdown iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm using react Native.
How to add Spinner in my app IOS as below image?

[image: Sample]

Comment: What have you tried? Google should be able to help. This site is meant to help with programming problems, not to provide entire solutions.

Comment: yes I googled.but there is not solution for it.https://github.com/alinz/react-native-dropdown. that's why I put question in here

Comment: use `UITableView` and create your own according to your requirement.

Comment: how to use it as a pop up in react native.

Comment: I also Tried with react native popover https://github.com/bulenttastan/react-native-list-popover .it also not working for me.